# I made a program, but can't seem to find the error, anyone has got a clue?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { //main function
    char string1[400] = "Pinot noir is a red wine grape variety of the species Vitis vinifera. The name may also refer to wines created predominantly from Pinot noir grapes. The name is derived from the French words for pine and black. The word pine alludes to the grape variety having tightly clustered, pine cone-shaped bunches of fruit.[1].";
    char string2[400] = "Metallica is an American heavy metal band. The band was formed in 1981 in Los Angeles by vocalist/guitarist James Hetfield and drummer Lars Ulrich, and has been based in San Francisco for most of its career.[1][2] The band's fast tempos, instrumentals and aggressive musicianship made them one of the founding big four bands of thrash metal, alongside Megadeth, Anthrax and Slayer.";

    char str[15]; //string declaration
    printf("Enter the word to be searched : ");
    scanf_s("%s", str); //taking word from user

    int i, k = 0, length = 0, count1 = 0, count2 = 0; //declaring required variables
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) { //calculate length of given word
        length++;
    }

    for (i = 0; string1[i] != '\0'; i++) { //loop through string1
        if (str[k] == string1[i]) { //if character of word equals to character of string1
            i++;
            if (k == length && string1[i - length] == ' ' && string1[i + 1] == ' ') { //checking spaces front and back of the word in string1
                count1++; //incrementing count
                k = 0;
            }
        } else {
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; string2[i] != '\0'; i++) { //same logic as we found word in string1
        if (str[k] == string2[i]) {
            k++;
            if (k == length && string1[i - length] == ' ' && string1[i + 1] == ' ')      {
                count2++;
                k = 0;
            }
        } else {
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("'%s' is found %d times in the String1.\n", str, count1); 
    //printing count in String1
    printf("'%s' is found %d times in the String2.", str, count2); 
    //printing count in String2
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting? hat did you expect to get? Have you tried debugging your program?

Comment: @einpoklum It seems it gets stuck, there is no output after entering "is". Should return a value

Comment: I guess `scanf_s("%s", str);` is wrong. What does it return?

Comment: @Mathieu scanf_s works fine on the other programs I am running (VS Studio 2019), tbh I am not even sure, if that's the problem

Comment: Hint: don't use fancy non standard stuff like `scanf_s`, use `scanf`. BTW: did you get compiler warnings? Consider them as errors

Comment: @Jabberwocky  I am getting the error if I use scanf: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question, providing details what you tried, how your program fails, and what debugging revealed. -- Please don't put additional information in comments, this is not a forum. -- You might want to [learn to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: That error messages tells you exactly what to do. Read the manual for `scanf_s` and decide if you want to use it instead. (Note the difference to `scanf`!) If not, define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Comment: @Eronsee Sure? From [ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160): "Unlike scanf, **scanf_s require you to specify buffer sizes for some parameters. ** "

Comment: You should have got another warninsg because of your misuse of `scanf_s`, anyway use `scanf` and add  `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the evry top of your sourc code as suggested in the warning.

Comment: Side note: you should learn about functions. Your repeating the exact same code for searching in `string1` and in `string2`, but your copy/paste failed because you didn't replace all occurences of `string1` with `string2` in that part. Look closely at your code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky unfortunately, same error as a above..but I have used scanf_s all the time so far, shouldn't be the main issue of the code. if you have another clue how to solve it. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @Eronsee make a genuine attempt to debug this yourself. Invest 30 minutes of your time to learn how to use the Visual Studio debugger. It's very powerful and yet very easy to use. The time invested will pay off very quickly. That being said, your usage of `scanf_s` is wrong (we have told you this several times). Don't use it, do what I suggest in my first comment. But there are most likely errors other than the misuse of `scanf_s`.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler complains because you are using `scanf_s` incorrectly.

Microsoft insists on using `scanf_s` instead of `scanf`, but just changing the function name is insufficient: you should pass the destination array size in addition to the destination array pointer.

The problem is Microsoft's version of `scanf_s` API differs from the C Standard version and this function is not supported on many platforms, making it non portable.

You should use the standard function `scanf` and pass the maximum number of characters to store into `str` this way:

```
   if (scanf("%14s", str) != 1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
       return 1;
   }
```

To prevent the compiler error, you can add this definition before the `#include <stdio.h>`:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
```

You scanning code is incorrect too:

- you will miss some matches such as `aab` in `aaab`
- the test for separators is incorrect and will fail or cause undefined behavior in all cases.
- you should use a function to avoid duplicating the code.

Here is a modified version:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count_matches(const char *s, const char *str) {
    size_t i, k, count = 0;

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || s[i - 1] != ' ') {
            // if at the beginning of a word, try matching
            for (k = 0;; k++) {
                if (str[k] == '\0') {
                    // check for end of word in s
                    if (s[i + k] == '\0' || s[i + k] == ' ')
                        count++;
                    break;
                }
                if (s[i + k] != str[k])
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() { //main function
    char string1[] = "Pinot noir is a red wine grape variety of the species Vitis vinifera. The name may also refer to wines created predominantly from Pinot noir grapes. The name is derived from the French words for pine and black. The word pine alludes to the grape variety having tightly clustered, pine cone-shaped bunches of fruit.[1].";
    char string2[] = "Metallica is an American heavy metal band. The band was formed in 1981 in Los Angeles by vocalist/guitarist James Hetfield and drummer Lars Ulrich, and has been based in San Francisco for most of its career.[1][2] The band's fast tempos, instrumentals and aggressive musicianship made them one of the founding big four bands of thrash metal, alongside Megadeth, Anthrax and Slayer.";

    char str[15];

    printf("Enter the word to be searched : ");
    if (scanf("%14s", str) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid or missing input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int count1 = count_matches(string1, str);
    int count2 = count_matches(string2, str);

    printf("'%s' is found %d times in the String1.\n", str, count1); 
    printf("'%s' is found %d times in the String2.\n", str, count2); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually if you omit `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, the usage of `scanf` triggers an error rather than just a warning: `foo.c(10,3): error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s... `. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding vendor-specific voodoo like `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in answers.